# Microsoft word 2015 just stopped checking for spelling errors

Tags: microsoft-word, spell-check

Not sure why this happened. I've checked my preferences and spell check is on. Apparently sdkvcjwdnvfkjn is a word in the English language.

I tried creating a new document but to no avail. I've completed two degrees, and this is the first time this has ever happened :/

Here are the spell check settings:

[image]

Here's an example of my problem (it's still underlining non-English words until it gets to the bottom):

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that sdkvcjwdnvfkjn is not a word in the English language. Does it flag up if you hit `F7`? Is spell check flagging it at all, or just not underlining it in red?

Comment: No I tried F7 and it didn't work.

Comment: I just added some pictures to my original post that illustrate the problem. Opening a brand new document fixes the problem. However cut and pasting that particular essay into a new document doesn't fix it. Spell check still works in general, but has stopped working for that particular section of my essay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, I think I know what happened. This is an EndNote thing. I got lazy and cut pasted the name of two authors into the sentence (see the bottom of the word document, "Schonert-Rehgjhyichl and Lawlor (2010)" were taken from an EndNote in-text reference).

It seems EndNote overrides spell-check -which is good as otherwise almost every name I reference in my essays would come up as mistakes. By cutting and pasting from the EndNote citation, that 'spell-check override' info must have carried over. Everything written after that was ignored by spell-check. I deleted that sentence and now everything works fine. The in-text references in the document that are underlined were written manually and so have nothing to do with EndNote.